# C++ Problema con entrada de datos

Tags: c++

Mi problema es a la hora de hacer un nuevo proceso, todo normal hasta que vuelvo a ingresar la cantidad de valores a comparar, me ignora las entradas de los nuevos valores o lo hace de forma errática ¿Como puedo arreglar esto?

Este es mi código.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int o, num, numax, numin, con1, con2;

int main ()    
{
    o=1;
    numax=0;
    numin=0;
    con1=0;

    while(o == 1)       
    {
        do          
        {
            cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tComparador de valores\n";
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t      <----------------------->\n\n";
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> Cuantos numeros desea comparar? ";
            cin >> con2;
            system ("cls");             
        }           
        while (con2 < 2);

        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tComparador de valores\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t      <----------------------->\n\n";

        do          
        {               
            do              
            {
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> Ingrese un numero: ";
                cin >> num;
                cout << "\n";
                if (num<1)
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> Ingrese un valor valido\n\n";
            }               
            while (num<1);

            con1++;
            if (num > numax)
                numax = num;
            if (numin == 0)
                numin=num;
            else if (numin > num)
                numin = num;

        }           
        while (con1 < con2);

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> El mayor es: ";
    cout << numax << "\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> El menor es: ";
    cout << numin << "\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> Desea hacer una nueva operacion?\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t1 Si\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t2 No\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t> Ingrese una opcion: ";
    cin >> o;

    if (o == 1)
        system("cls");      
    }

    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t> Saliendo...\n\n";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes describir mejor el tipo de cálculos _valores usados, descripición del problema_ y los resultados que intentas obtener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de:

```cpp
int main ()    
{
    o=1;
    numax=0;
    numin=0;
    con1=0;

    while(o == 1)       
    {
        do          
        {
            cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tComparador de valores\n";
```

Prueba con:

```cpp
int main ()    
{
    o=1;

    while(o == 1)       
    {
        numax=0;
        numin=0;
        con1=0;

        do          
        {
            con2=0;
            cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tComparador de valores\n";
```

Acuérdate de limpiar las variables antes de iniciar cada proceso.
También puedes optar por usar un bucle `for` para solicitar cada número, en lugar del `while`, aprovechando que se puede saber la cantidad de iteraciones, gracias a la variable `con2`.

Comment: Gracias amigo, veo que me equivoque en algo tan obvio, probare lo del for, salu2

Comment: Creo que vale la pena decir que el ámbito de las variables `numax`, `numin` y `con1` puede ser reducido al ámbito del primer bucle `while` y que no es ni buena idea ni tiene sentido que `o` y `num` seas variables en espacio estàtico (global).

Comment: Capto lo que quieres decir @PaperBirdMaster que las variables numax, numin y con1 seria mejor que esten dentro del primer while, pero no comprendo el porque es malo que o y num esten fue del main, es decir, pienso que no afecta en nada al programa, y que es espacio estatico? agradeceria tus respuestas amigo

Comment: @Malthael esas dudas que te plantean mi comentario son suficientemente interesantes como para merecer una pregunta propia en lugar de un comentario, ¿serías tan amable de formular las preguntas? :)